# Configuring AutoMapper Maps for Dynamic/Expando Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, automapper

I'm using AutoMapper to map ExpandoObjects to an Entity and want to configure some rules for the mappings, specifically, I don't want to map to any property that inherits from Entity; I tried to set Ignore on those properties, but it never executes for the top level object, I hit the break point for the properties of the Entity that inherit from Entity string => Entity, but never for ExpandoObject => Entity.

**Startup.cs**

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddAutoMapper(config =>
  {
    config.ForAllMaps((cfg, expr) =>
    {
      if (typeof(Entity).IsAssignableFrom(cfg.DestinationType))
      {
        var properties = cfg.DestinationType.GetProperties()
            .Where(prop => typeof(Entity).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType));

        foreach (var prop in properties)
        {
          expr.ForMember(prop.Name, opt => opt.Ignore());
        }
      }
    });

    config.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true;
    config.ValidateInlineMaps = false;
  });
```

I found some code that works, but I was hoping to find a way to do it that wasn't global.

```
.AddAutoMapper(config =>
{
  config.ShouldMapProperty = pi => !typeof(Entity).IsAssignableFrom(pi.PropertyType);

  config.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true;
  config.ValidateInlineMaps = false;
});
```

Is there a way to configure maps for ExpandoObjects? The documentation shows how to map them, but it doesn't have any information on configuring the maps for them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, mapping from `ExpandoObject` is built in and doesn't work like a regular map you create yourself. And there is no way to configure it.
[Here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/4178101ed7aee5ef193c3c4230981b493a13b2c4/src/AutoMapper/Mappers/FromStringDictionaryMapper.cs#L33) is the code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use the workaround mentioned above until I can completely replace the mapper in these instances.